# HTML Wrapper Not Properly Filling Page

Tags: html, css, wrapper, footer, viewport

I'm putting together a small site for a friend (I'm not really that much of an expert as you can probably tell!).

We're experimenting with some design ideas and have come to a bit of a block.

The page in question is: http://westleemusic.co.uk/concept/epdownload.php

Basically when the window is resized so that the bottom of the viewport is high than the bottom of the content (in this case it's the "iPhone Users Click Here To Download"), the translucent background wrapper decides that it no longer wants to fill the page.

I've been sat here for a few hours trying to figure it out and I'm stumped. As I said previously, I'm a n00b when it comes to this stuff so I'm hoping one of you masters can help!

Let me know if you need more info!

Many thanks

Comment: What is it exactly you're asking? What is the specific code you need help with? What have you tried? Please include it here as well as an attached jsfiddle.net to demonstrate.

Comment: Works for me. What browser are you seeing this in?

Comment: I'm not sure whats wrong, but I can tell you that you should check out the HTML `<pre>` tag, which allows you to put the text exactly as it is typed, spaces, indentations and all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the height of wrapper to auto. This will cause it to fill the entire screen even when you start scrolling.

Comment: Though its now made my footer div not stay at the bottom of the page as it used to :/

Comment: How is your footer positioned?